# MVC4 annotation conditional validation depending on input of another field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my model:

```
Primary
{

public Boolean Yes { get; set; }

public Boolean NoHome { get; set; }    



public int mailzip
public string mailcity 
public string mailstate    

}
```

i have 2 fields based on which required field validation via annotation must be done on a textbox

1. one of them is a checkbox (condition for required field to activate `->` this must be checked)

   ```
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.nohome, new { name = "NoHome", id = "NoHome" })
   ```

OR

1. The other is a `@Html.RadioButtonFor pair` - the below must be clicked as yes for the required field to be validated

   ```
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.primary.yes, "true", new { name = "DifferentAddress", id = "DifferentAddressYes" })
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.primary.no, "true", new { name = "DifferentAddress", id = "DifferentAddressYes" })
   ```

Either of the above two fields should be able to fire the required field attribute on the below 3 fields

```
mailzip
mailcity 
mailstate
```

Comment: You might want to change your public fields to properties. And if you want to perform custom validation like this, you should investigate `IValidatableObject`